# Prevent MSGBOX from popping up from individual sheet when Workbook_BeforeClose is activated on close

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and to Excel. I was wondering if there is away that I could prevent a message box from appearing on close from and individual worksheet when the Workbook_BeforeClose script runs? Below will be the on Workbook_BeforeClose Script and then separate will be the individual worksheet msgbox that runs when I don't want it to. I would like to be able to achieve this so it's not annoying to users on close. Suggestions?

Additional information: Everything in my main "On close" Script I would like to remain the same. I just only do not want the Individual worksheet object to activate on close as well. Because my on close script locks the dashboard so that users are forced to enable macros so it goes through the sheets and hides them. Well in that process it also activated that sheet and shows the MSGBOX that I dont want from the "Individual Worksheet Object:" I want it not to show up when "Workbook_BeforeClose:" is activated.

Workbook_BeforeClose:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim sDateTime As String, sFileName As String

 Sheets("START").Visible = xlSheetVisible
 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 If ws.Name <> "START" Then
 ws.Visible = xlVeryHidden
 End If
 Next ws
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     If ThisWorkbook.Readonly = True Then GoTo Passed2
     GoTo Passed3
 Passed2:
     If IsWorkbookOpen("CCC_Error_Tracker.xlsm") Then
         MsgBox "Excel has detected that your `Team Error Tracker` is still open and has not been saved. The Opportunities Dashboard will now close. As a reminder, in order to save your data, you must close ProcessID: `CCC_Error_Tracker.xlsm`", vbInformation
     End If
     GoTo End1:
 Passed3:
 CodeRetry:
     On Error GoTo Failed
         If Me.Saved = True And BackupReqd = False Then Exit Sub
     With ThisWorkbook
         sDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm"
         sFileName = Replace(.Name, ".xlsm", sDateTime)
         .SaveCopyAs Filename:="P:\WI\Teams\Programs\J&J CCC\Care Specialist\Alicia's Team\FPA RESULTS\Supporting_Files\FPA_FILE_BACKUPS\Opportunities_Dashboard\" & sFileName
      GoTo Passed
 Failed:
  GoTo CodeRetry
 Passed:
 ThisWorkbook.Save
 MsgBox "Your data has been saved and backed-up successfully! Your backup will be stored for 72 hours before discarded to save disk space. Email Blank@Blank.com if you have a suggestion."
 GoTo End2
 End1:
     Application.Quit
 End2: 
 End With 
 End Sub
```

Individual Worksheet Object:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 If ThisWorkbook.Readonly = True Then GoTo Readonly
     GoTo Editmode
 Readonly:
 MsgBox "You're currently in read only mode and cannot save feedback. If you continue to provide feedback, you will lose all data on close."
 Editmode:
 End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried deleting those lines out?  I bet that will keep them from showing up...

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe I did not explain this correctly. Everything in my main "On close" Script I would like to remain the same. I just only do not want the Individual worksheet object to activate on close as well. Because my on close script locks the dashboard so that users are forced to enable macros so it goes through the sheets and hides them. Well in that process it also activated that sheet and shows the MSGBOX that I dont want from the "Individual Worksheet Object:" I want it not to show up when "Workbook_BeforeClose:" is activated. Let me know if that makes more sense?

Comment: I wish I had the time to mock up an example, but unfortunately I do not.  One way you could go about it is to have a public Boolean variable called something like "ClosingEvent" which gets set to True at the start of your closing event.  Then modify your Worksheet_Activate event slight by adding a If Not ClosingEvent statement around your msgbox.  That way, it will only get executed when ClosingEvent = False (which is the default value on initialization).  If no one posts a better solution, I'll try and mock something up quickly when I get a free minute.

Comment: I will take a stab on it. I am not sure 100% on this.  If you get some time an example would be great. Thanks though

Comment: OK, added an example.  Hope it gets you close :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's see if this gets you close.  There may be other ways, but here is one way to go about it.  This is just for demonstration and learning purposes, so I'm using a new workbook rather than your existing code.  Hopefully you'll see how it works and be able to modify your code to suit your needs.

Step 1:  Create a new workbook and add a few worksheets (my example has 3).

Step 2:  add some code to the Worksheeet_Activate event for each worksheet.  Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    If Not ClosingEvent Then MsgBox Sheet1.Name

End Sub
```

modify the sheet reference for each worksheet.

Step 3: Add a new module and at the top put this:

```
Public ClosingEvent As Boolean
```

Step 4:  In the Workbook_BeforeClose event, add this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ClosingEvent = True

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
    Next ws

    ' this is here for testing, to keep the workbook from actually closing.
    Cancel = True
    ClosingEvent = False

End Sub
```

Now click each tab and see that message box?  Look what happens when you close the workbook, no message boxes!  Feel free to step through the close event so you can see each worksheet activate does run, but since you set the flag to only run when it's not the closing event, it skips over the message box. If you don't believe me, comment out the ClosingEvent = True line in the BeforeClose event and rerun the code...

Hope that helps!  If you need more assistance, please post back.